# Could you please explain me why it is not needed to put a value inside a promise function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I mean, why it is not needed? I would always write there a value. However I've recently seen a code without it. Why is it possible. Could you explain me the logic why it is not mandatory? Thanks for an answer so much!

```
const TaskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean
    }
})

const Task = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema)

const task = new Task({
    name: 'Buy a new macBook Pro',
    completed: false
})

task.save().then(() => {
    console.log(task)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: there is no "promise function" in the code you posted ... there's a function that returns a promise ...

Comment: can you please clarify your question? Which part of the code snippet is confusing you?

Comment: task.save().then(()  => ....................   <<== I was just confused that nothing is provided inside the function that is written in 'then()'

Comment: @MarekM that just means that you don't care about what value is returned from the `save` promise. If you did care, you'd give the argument a name, and use it inside the body of the function. But there's no need to specify it if you don't use it - as here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature of language Javascript, not only promise callbacks. Any number of arguments (including zero) can be passed to a function regardless of its definition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that behind the scenes methods like .then() are just wrappers for callback functions that take promise resolutions and pass them to whatever function you provide inside the parenthesis. .then() for example, is designed to always pass the promise resolution (if it was resolved) to the function you put inside. That process is just abstracted away from your human/developer view.